# MVVM- Trigger Storyboard in the View Model in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I have a couple of Storyboards in my view that I would like to trigger from the ViewModel if possible. Is there a simple way or elegant way of doing this. Here is what I am trying to do.

Person Clicks on a Button-->RelayCommand (In the ViewModel), the Relay Command should then play the storyboard.  Also one more thing, I would like to also trigger the storyboard animation by itself in the ViewModel without any interaction.

```
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
 <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ButtonPress}"                                                     CommandParameterValue="RedButtonLight">
    </cmd:EventToCommand>
         </i:EventTrigger>
          </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's a long time ago. But I've written a detailed blog post about Triggering Storyboards and MVVM.

http://mark.mymonster.nl/2010/12/14/trigger-a-storyboard-on-viewmodel-changes/

Comment: Worked for me after I added ControlStoryboardProperty="Play" to the ControlStoryboardAction.  <ei:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardProperty="Play" x:Name="FadeOutOnLogin" Storyboard="{StaticResource LoginFadeOut}"/>

Answer (score 1):

If the button click is purely to power a view-related thing and isn't doing any actual application logic, then I would argue that you can do all this in the code-behind of the view class.

If this isn't the case then I would use a property on the Presentation (ViewModel) to signal that the Presentation is in a state, and have the view react to the PropertyChanged event and start the storyboard.  This is assuming you are implimenting INotifyPropertyChanged on your Presentation class.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [expression samples](http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/). There is a trigger for events from the datacontext. `DataEventTrigger`

You could use that to trigger a `ControlStoryboardAction` to start the story board whenever your viewmodel raises a particular event.

Your viewmodel could then raise the event as part of the command as well as at other times.

Answer (score 0):

Heres how you can do it in blend without touching a line of xaml or code : 
http://www.basarat.com/2011/05/expression-blend-starting-storyboard.html