# Start storyboard in Prism Shell based on button click inside region

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm using Prism to build a WPF application but have some trouble getting the following to work. I have a `Storyboard` inside my `Shell.xaml` file. The storyboard should be triggered by a button in a user control in a region. My `Shell.xaml` looks like this:

```
<Window ...>
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Storyboard x:Key="myStoryboard">...</Storyboard>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>
  <ContentControl x:Name="wizard" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MyRegion" />
</Window>
```

The button is attached to a command in a view model. The user control that is injected into the region `MyRegion` looks like this:

```
<UserControl ...>
  <Button x:Name="myButton" Command="{Binding WizardCommand}">
    MyButton
  </Button>
</UserControl>
```

And finally the view model that corresponds to the previous user control:

```
[Export(typeof(MyViewModel))]
public class MyViewModel
{
  private readonly DelegateCommand _wizardCommand;
  public ICommand WizardCommand { get { return _wizardCommand; } }

  public MyViewModel()
  {
    _wizardCommand = new DelegateCommand(StartWizard);
  }

  private void StartWizard()
  {
    ??????
  }
}
```

What steps should I take to run the storyboard `myStoryboard` inside `Shell.xaml` from the `WizardCommand` inside the region `MyRegion`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have 2 questions here:

1. How to notify Shell that it needs to do something.
2. How to run storyboard from ViewModel

Here is what I would do:

1. Use PRISM's `EventAggregator`, create `RunMyStoryboard` event. Subscribe to this event in your `ShellViewModel` and publish this event in your `MyViewModel.StartWizard`
2. Check this question on how to run Storyboard from ViewModel: [MVVM- Trigger Storyboard in the View Model in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548291/mvvm-trigger-storyboard-in-the-view-model-in-silverlight)